# No constructor defined?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

In my C# Console Application, Visual Studio 2010 highlights `new FeatureClassNameClass()` in my below line of code and states `"ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.FeatureClassNameClass has No constructors defined"` and then states cannot be embedded. Use aplicable interface instead.  How else can I define `pOutFeatClassName` as type `IFeatureClassName`?

```
IFeatureClassName pOutFeatClassName = new FeatureClassNameClass();
```

If I change the code to below, then Visual Studio does not throw an immediate error but once I run my application Visual Studio immediately bombs at this line and only states `"error vshost32.exe"`.  What is going on?  Many Thanks for any suggestions..

```
IFeatureClassName pOutFeatClassName = (IFeatureClassName)new FeatureClassName();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you initializing ?

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new DesktopConsoleApplication1.LicenseInitializer();
    [STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
        m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(
            new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo },
            new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { });

        try
        {
            IFeatureClassName fcn = new FeatureClassNameClass();
            ((IDatasetName)fcn).Name = "test";
            Console.WriteLine(((IDatasetName)fcn).Name);               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("press enter to close window");
        Console.ReadLine();

        //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
        //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()
        m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
    }
}
```

This LicenseInitializer code was created by the VS2010 project template for New arcgis console app:

```
internal partial class LicenseInitializer
{
    public LicenseInitializer()
    {
        ResolveBindingEvent += new EventHandler(BindingArcGISRuntime);
    }

    void BindingArcGISRuntime(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // TODO: Modify ArcGIS runtime binding code as needed
        //
        if (!RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Desktop))
        {
            // Failed to bind, announce and force exit
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid ArcGIS runtime binding. Application will shut down.");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirk-  above my Main I have private static IAoInitialize m_pAoInitialize;  And in my Main I have IAoInitialize ao = new AoInitialize();
                ao.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo); Is there any issue with the way I have setup my licenseInitializer?

Comment: I'm able to go through other functions that use ArcObjects and I don't get an error there.  But if I have not initialized my licenseinitialzer the best way then I need to

Comment: If you are on arc10.0, you'll need to use the runtime binding. http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002ns000000

Comment: Hi Kirk-  I had forgot to include another line of my code where I do actually do the runtime binding so I believe I am doing that correctly.  Besides, there are a number of other functions that use ArcObjects that I have no trouble on.  Neil Clemmons on ESRI forums responded with an interesting response in the below link.  I still don't understand why FeatureClassName has no constructor based on what he said but I will try to do what he suggests.  Your thoughts?  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/22723-What-is-the-best-syntax-here?p=74333#post74333

Comment: What happens if you create a new project (new arcgis console app) with references to necessary assemblies, then copy and paste the code I posted?

Comment: desktopConsoleApplication1 could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?) is the error I get first.  I get some other errors but that may get fixed if I can fix this error first

Comment: If I change that private static line to private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new LicenseInitializer();  then I get an error at m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication stating Program.LicenseInitialzer does not contain a definition for InitialzeApplication

Comment: Ok I tried creating a new "Arcgis console app" instead of a Console App and I don't see the option in my project templates for Visual Studio 2010.  How can I get that?

Comment: Did you choose "3.5 framework" in the dropdown? (templates are not available for .NET 4.0)

Comment: Thanks Kirk-  I created a ArcGIS Console App thnaks to your insight.  I'm getting errors at esriLicenseProductCode and esriLicenseExtensionCode and Visual Studio states the type esriLicenseProductCode exists in both E:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet\ESRI.ArcGIS.System.dll and C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\ESRI.ArcGIS.System\10.0_8...\ESRI.ArcGIS.System.dll   So Do you happen to know how I can fix that?

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of that last error I mentioned.  I think you got me going in the right direction kirk.  I'll test out my code now and select "answered" for this question in just a short while

Comment: This is strange but after using this new ArcGIS console app which already has your code in it and I added my functions with proper references, it continues to error at this line  m_productStatus.Add(prod, status);  stating all arcinfo linceses are checked out.  When I check ArcGIS Administrator, I see that there are over 23 licenses of Info available and 'm able to open ArcGIS desktop, etc.  Thoughts?

Comment: Are you running a 10.0 license server?

Comment: yes my arcgis adminsitrator is pointed to a 10.0 license server.

Comment: Based on your earlier error where the type is found in the GAC and in the dev kit folder, I think you have an install issue.  Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the ArcObjects SDK for .NET?

Comment: I'll give that a shot now and will keep you posted.  Thanks Kirk

Comment: Hi Kirk-  I removed the ArcObjects SDK and then reinstalled it and am still getting "licensecheckedout" as the status so its preventing me from using ArcObjects for Info.  I wasn't really having this issue with using the regular console app so I may try that again and see if the fresh install of sdk fixed my original issue with FeatureClassNameClass object

Comment: You were right Kirk.  Thank you for all your help.  My app is working now

Answer (score 22):

The solution:

1. In your project references, find the assembly where FeatureClassNameClass is (ie ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase).
2. Right-click it and select "properties"
3. Change "Embed interop types" to "false"

This 99% should do the trick

Comment: Same here. This solved it perfectly for me. Don't know why this isn't the accepted answer

Comment: This was the solution for me as well.  Had the issue after upgrading a project from ArcGIS 10.3 to 10.4 and changing the .net framework from 3.5 to 4.5