# The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.WorkspaceClass' has no constructors defined

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, workspace

I am using a map application (ArcGIS Engine). I am trying to start an edit session and i want to use IWorkSpace interface in the WorkSpaceClass. but i am getting "The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.WorkspaceClass' has no constructors defined." I read the post [No constructor defined?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/no-constructor-defined) but it did not help. can anyone help?

```
IWorkspaceEdit edit = new WorkspaceClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to point `edit` to an existing workspace object not the base class. So you need to get a handle on the workspace you intend to edit before you point an *IWorkspaceEdit* interface to it.

Search the API help for the page "Editing with the geodatabase API" there are several code samples to get you going.